# How do I open a new form from a wpf form and still be able to click back and forth between the forms?

Tags: wpf, showdialog

I have a main wpf form that opens a new form. However when that form opens, I'm unable to click back to the original one and use that form. The original form is locked until I close the newly opened form. How do I open both forms so that the previous form can be at the very least moved around and given focus to?

Within the mainForm, there is a method that calls newForm.ShowDialog();

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Show() rather than ShowDialog()

Answer (score 0):

Yes show() Function is used for using the form as a new independent form 
and showDialog() Function is used for using the form as a chilled for the current form.